# Is this function continuous and differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, differential

The function is $G(x,y)= 1$ if $y \neq e^{x}$ and $0$ if $y= e^{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not continuous in the natural topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$, because a continuous function cannot assume exactly two values.

Therefore it is not differentiable, either.